# Shapefiles for Paraguay

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for the latest shapefiles of the whole Paraguay:

1. Soil type
2. Contour
3. Land use
4. Precipitation
5. Administrative boundary
6. Open green space
7. Built-up area

I have looked at it on the national geo-portal of Paraguay, but could not find it. I also have looked through other geo-portal.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you think this is better suited for OpenData.SE?

Comment: Admin Boundaries https://github.com/justinelliotmeyers/official_paraguay_administrative_boundary_shapefile

Answer (score 1):

[OpenStreetMap Data Extracts](https://osm-internal.download.geofabrik.de/south-america/paraguay.html)

This server has data extracts from the [OpenStreetMap project](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) which are normally updated every day. (If you have been directed to this page from elsewhere and are not familiar with OpenStreetMap, we highly recommend that you read up on OSM before you use the data.) This open data download service is offered free of charge by Geofabrik GmbH.

**[Link to Download](https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/paraguay.html#)**

[OpenStreetMap Data
in
Layered GIS Format](https://download.geofabrik.de/osm-data-in-gis-formats-free.pdf)

[paraguay-latest-free.shp.zip](https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/paraguay-latest-free.shp.zip), yields a number of ESRI compatible shape files when unzipped. ([Format description PDF](https://download.geofabrik.de/osm-data-in-gis-formats-free.pdf)) This file was last modified 6 hours ago. File size: 169 MB; MD5 sum: [b3bd6ba7a8abe4b2562d05c5f08581f5](https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/paraguay-latest-free.shp.zip.md5).

[Other Formats](https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/paraguay.html#)